# IONIC 2 save and unsave button

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic2

I want to create a save and unsaves icon in my list. When I click, it saves and changes the icon, then when I click again , it I click again it unsaves and  changes the icon again.

in my page.html

```
 <ion-col>
    <button  id="heart" float-end  (click)="savePost(i)" *ngIf="item.save == true">
        <ion-icon [name]="heartFilled[i]" id="saveHeart"></ion-icon
    </button>
    <button  id="heart" float-end  (click)="deletePost( i)" *ngIf="item.save != true"  >
       <ion-icon [name]="heartoutline[i]" id="saveHeart" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

where i is the index of the item in the list .

In my page.ts

```
savePost(i  ){
    this.heartFilled[i]="heart-outline"

}


deletePost(i ){
    this.heartoutline[i]="heart"
}
```

I initiate the icon variables like this :

```
this.heartoutline.push("heart-outline")
this.heartFilled.push("heart")
```

I can change the icons on click but not change them back once they are changed. Also, I am not sure how to switch between the save and unsave functions .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use index to change your item. Just use your `item` object.
Your item should have propertives to store `icon` and `save`. It should look like that:

```
{
  //Some propertives
  icon: "heart-outline",
  save: false
}
```

In the template, you do like that:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button  id="heart" float-end  (click)="toggleSave(item)">
        <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" id="saveHeart"></ion-icon
    </button> 
</ion-col>
```

And your functionc should be:

```
toggleSave(item){
   item.save = !item.save;
   if(item.save)
     item.icon = "heart";
   else item.icon = "heart-outline";
}
```